# calculating distance between coordinates in a list

Tags: python-3.x

```
myDict={"pizzaHut" : ["PizzaHut", [155, 407], [1100, 2200], "halal", "fast-food", [10.00, 30.00], "Hawaiian Ala-Carte ($10.80)"],
"starbucks" : ["Starbucks Coffee", [155, 407], [700, 2200], "halal", "beverages", [6.00, 11.00], "Vanilla Latte ($6.70)"],
"subway" : ["Subway", [155, 407], [800, 2100], "halal", "fast-food", [5.00, 10.00], "Chicken Teriyaki Sandwich ($6.70)"]}

x = input("What is the x-coordinate of your location?")
y = input("What is the y-coordinate of your location?")

i want to find the distance of the different eateries from the location input by the user, how do i do that? Really new to python so i dont know how to start

datalist = list(myDict.values())

destinationList = []

for i in datalist:
    destinationList.append([i[0],i[1]])

distance = []
def distance (x, y,destinationList):
    for element in destinationList:
        x1 = element[1][0]
        y1 = element[1][1]
    distance.append((((x1-x)**2)+((y1-y)**2))**0.5)
print(distance)
```

but this doesn't work. 
The output should be a list of 3 calculated distance of user location from the 3 eateries

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please invest a few minutes in improving your question. Reading [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be a good idea! Keep in mind that we don't have any context in regards to what you're trying to achieve and as much as code is important, when the question contains only a code-dump without an explanation of what are you trying to do, what is the expected output and what is failing - it's very difficult to help you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The complete code

```
myDict={"pizzaHut" : ["PizzaHut", [155, 407], [1100, 2200], "halal", "fast-food", [10.00, 30.00], "Hawaiian Ala-Carte ($10.80)"],
"starbucks" : ["Starbucks Coffee", [155, 407], [700, 2200], "halal", "beverages", [6.00, 11.00], "Vanilla Latte ($6.70)"],
"subway" : ["Subway", [155, 407], [800, 2100], "halal", "fast-food", [5.00, 10.00], "Chicken Teriyaki Sandwich ($6.70)"]}

x = int(input("What is the x-coordinate of your location?\n"))
y = int(input("What is the y-coordinate of your location?\n"))


datalist = list(myDict.values())

destinationList = []

for i in datalist:
    destinationList.append([i[0],i[1]])

distance = []
def find_distance(x, y,destinationList):
    for element in destinationList:
        x1 = element[1][0]
        y1 = element[1][1]
        distance.append((((x1-x)**2)+((y1-y)**2))**0.5)
    print(distance)

find_distance(x,y,destinationList)
```

Comment: it still doesnt work                                                                                                   
What is the x-coordinate of your location?210
What is the y-coordinate of your location?320
<function distance at 0x000001FC1514FAE8>

Comment: see edits for the code; there is a naming conflict.

Comment: If you have any issue with the answer it is better to ask in the comments rather than downvoting the answer.

Comment: there is no distance displayed

Comment: did you call the function?

Comment: sorry about the downvoting, as im new to this it was accidental

Comment: how does one call a function?

Comment: you call a function like `find_distance(x,y,destinationList)`. See the complete code in answer.

Comment: what is the /n for?

Comment: `\n` is for newline printing

Comment: Glad to help. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Remeber to ask for doubts politely in comments. Upvote helpful answers, if any answer works for you mark it as Accepted, and downvote incorrect answers.

Comment: If i wanted to show the name of eateries along with the calculated distance like e.g.[pizza hut: dist1, starbuck: dist2, subway:dist3], how do i do that?

Comment: for the required format replace `print(distance)` with `[print(p[0],d) for d,p in zip(distance,destinationList)]`

Comment: i tried upping the vote several times but this appeared: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: if you don't mind, could you briefly explain how [print(p[0],d) for d,p in zip(distance,destinationList)] this code works? What is p, d and zip?

Comment: 1. `zip` packs two things into a single thing
2. `p,d` again unpack it to 2 things;here first is an array
3. indexing starts from 0 so `p[0]` gets the first thing in the array

Comment: Okay thank you so so much!!! But i'm also really sorry about the downvote.